# GridGain requirements for a cache key where value is to be used with Sql Queries

Tags: gridgain

I am trying to execute a `GridCacheQuery` created with `createSqlQuery()` on a cache that I am using a custom Key type for. The problem is that this always gives me back an empty collection, even when there are matching results.

If I repeat the test with a non-custom key type, such as `String` or `Integer`, I get the results back that I would expect.

If I repeat the test using a `createSqlFieldsQuery()` query, this time with the custom key again, I also get the results I would expect!

Is this behaviour expected? I have tested this with 6.5.0-p1, and my custom key type overrides `hashCode()` and `equals()`, and even implements `Comparable`, for what it's worth.

Comment: Can you paste your code for invoking SQL query with `createSqlQuery` method?

Comment: OK, I think I've got to the bottom of this one. I had double quotes around the table name in my query using `createSqlQuery()`, and not in the other query. Removing the quotes seems to fix the problem. I'm sure this used to work with double quotes. Anyway ...